# Why doesn't Catalyst support routes dispatching

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm wondering why [`Catalyst`](http://www.catalystframework.org/) does not have a routes-based dispatching mechanism. Does anyone have insights on that?

I know most of it would be achievable with chained methods, but I sometimes struggle with them (my bad, I know). I used routes in [`Mojolicious`](http://mojolicio.us/) and they feel somewhat more comfortable.

I'm tempted to roll my own based on [`Path::Router`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Router), but before I embark on such a project I thought I'd ask some wise people.

And, while I'm at it, is there any good source for understanding dispatching in `Catalyst`, beside reading the code?

Thanks-

Comment: "I thought I'd ask some wise men" -- I'm fairly sure there are plenty of wise women using perl, too...

Comment: What do you miss from the routes-based dispatching? It might be worth looking at the "special actions" - index, default, auto, begin and end. With some combination of them and the routing module hierarchy (Foo::Bar etc) it's possible to acheive a lot - https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Catalyst-Manual/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod#Built-in-special-actions

Comment: @plusplus I know the same result _can_ be achieved with use of chained methods and special action, or even better with regex-base ones - it's just that having the whole thing in one place with something like `Route('/foo/:bar/:baz')` seems less unwieldy.

Comment: It does. Everything is a route. They're just not written the way you would prefer them to be.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to construct routes as the dispatching mechanism in Catalyst. [This SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8073390/14750) discusses it, and the meaty part can be found in [this Advent Calendar article](http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2008/11).

That first link will also refer you to The Definitive Guide to Catalyst, a book well worth getting hold of. Dispatching is discussed at length therein.